# angular populate autocomplete field from data taken from a php url

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, autocomplete, yii2-advanced-app

Iam using an autocomplete field which need to take data to be listed from mysql database based on php (YII2 ) action. Currently the autocomplete field populated statically. 
The code used to populate the autocomplete filed is given below.

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

function DemoCtrl($timeout, $q) {
    var self = this;

    // list of `state` value/display objects
    self.states = loadAll();
    self.selectedItem = null;
    self.searchText = null;
    self.querySearch = querySearch;

    // ******************************
    // Internal methods
    // ******************************

    /**
     * Search for states... use $timeout to simulate
     * remote dataservice call.
     */
    function querySearch(query) {
        var results = query ? self.states.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : self.states;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function () {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    /**
     * Build `states` list of key/value pairs
     */
    function loadAll() {
        var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
              Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
              Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
              Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
              North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
              South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
              Wisconsin, Wyoming';

        return allStates.split(/, +/g).map(function (state) {
            return {
                value: state.toLowerCase(),
                display: state
            };
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create filter function for a query string
     */
    function createFilterFor(query) {
        var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

        return function filterFn(state) {
            return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
        };

    }
}
```

Here in function loadall(), I need to take values from my database, which is returned from my YII2 controller action. It can be accesed via url My controller action is as given below

```
public function actionGetAllPackages()
{
    $packages = \common\models\Packages::find()
            ->select('name')
            ->all();
    $name = "";
    foreach ($packages as $package)
    {
        $name = $name.', '.$package->name;
  }
     $name = substr($name, 2);
    echo addslashes($name);
}
```

How can I take the value printed att the controller action to angular function ? Please help . Iam using YII2 and angular for the first time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call a $http request to your `GetAllPackages()` function in the controller, within the `loadAll()` method in your script and assign that value to `allstates`.